# Why does Doctor Samuel Loomis tape Michael Myers with black & white tapes?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-2007

In *Halloween* (2007), Dr. Samuel Loomis took an observation job over Michael Myers in some facility and he started taping his behavior also in **black & white**.  Why would he record in black & white for his observations?

[image: Young Michael Myers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most "observational" cameras to this day are B&W.  How often do you see store security footage that's in color?  B&W cameras were, and are still, less expensive than their color counterparts.

Don't forget; the original movie was released in 1978.  Based on that, we can assume young Michael was under observation in the late 50's/early 60's.

There's a little bit of info on surveillance cameras [here](https://www.ncjrs.gov/school/ch2a_6.html).  The highlights are:

- Color cameras usually have lower resolution than black-and-white cameras.
- Currently, the cost of a color camera as compared to an equivalent black-and-white camera is anywhere from 30 percent to 70 percent greater.

Based on the timeframe of late 50's/early 60's, the disparity in price was probably much greater.

Comment: In the original film, Michael Myers was institutionalized in 1963 at the age of 6.

Comment: Black and white data is also more compressible, meaning you can store more of it onto tape/disk/whatever you dump to.